# Win10; Macrium Reflect - Cloning HD to SSD, unable to boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm trying to clone my 1TB spinning MBR disk to a 1TB ssd (also MBR).

1. Install the new SSD onto a spare sata port
2. Boot to windows 10, run Macrium Reflect v7.3.5321 (free edition).
3. Select 'Clone this disk' and walk through the steps to put the same partitions onto the SSD.
4. Wait an hour.
5. Turn off. Pull power on old drive. Turn on.
6. In bios, ensure boot order is set to the new SSD first. F10 SAVE, reboot.
7. Wait a bit at the flashing cursor where it normally loads the OS
8. [image: windows can't be found; it's not C:] This old gem. Note no drive letter on that path.
9. Turn off. Replace power on old drive. Turn on.
10. Back how it was. Didn't even need to re-set the boot order.
11. Start over, try again, same result.

Here's the drives in Macrium: They have the same partitions, same types, same sizes.

[image]

Diskpart detail on the disk looks like this:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          953 GB    22 GB
  Disk 2    Online          111 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         4657 GB      0 B
  Disk 5    Online           28 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.
DISKPART> detail disk

SPCC Solid State Disk
Disk ID: 8AC5EA1E
Type   : SATA
Status : Online
Path   : 2
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1100)#ATA(C02T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 2                             Partition    579 MB  Healthy    Offline
  Volume 3     F                NTFS   Partition    930 GB  Healthy
```

I note that the disk doesn't say it's a boot disk. Is that a thing I can change, or does that just represent the current 'system'?

Here's my system summary (yes it's old):

[image]

/edit: details of my mechanical drive

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.610

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: TIM

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          953 GB    22 GB
  Disk 2    Online          111 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         4657 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

ST1000DM003-1SB102
Disk ID: D7E219C0
Type   : SATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1100)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    579 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    930 GB  Healthy    Boot

DISKPART>
```

Comment: Is this a NVMe drive by chance?  I suspect half of your problem is the fact it’s MBR and not GPT thus allowing for UEFI mode. Can you provide the output on the traditional mechanical drive on the equivalent volume?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a Silicon Power A55 3d nand drive. Added diskpart details above. Tried converting drive to GPT, then cloning the system partition to it, then rebooting to it - it just shows a flashing cursor, no OS missing message or anything.

Comment: Did you remember to disable Legacy mode?

Comment: Yes. Flashing cursor, doesn't boot. Thought it might be a dud drive so I installed Windows 10 from a usb stick on it independantly and that worked and booted fine, so the drive itself is fine. But I have several profiles on the machine and don't want to have to just start over. Have also tried DiskGenius software (in WinPE mode, took 2x time that Marcium did) which also didn't boot even after successful clone.

Comment: These profiles on something other than the system drive?

Comment: No, it's standard windows. Everything is on C:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116354/discussion-between-frumbert-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Migrate my OS from a Hard Disk to a SSD freely and quickly, I can only recommend Clonezilla. Out of all the products I tried (some I had to pay for) this was the only one that worked as advertised.

1. You get Clonezilla from https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php and then click on `Stable-(numbers)` and the on the next screen change the file type to `iso` and download the iso file.
2. You then have to put it on a usb stick (I used a 2GB memory stick, it doesn't hve to be big) using Rufus (https://rufus.ie/).
3. You then boot your pc using the USB stick and *read every screen very carefully*, because it's not a friendly GUI-based app like the rest.
4. Once you confirm what you are doing, confirm it again, and AGAIN, it was a fairly painless process what was way faster than the other products I tried.
5. Once done, shut the PC down, remove the old hard disk, and turn the PC back on.

For future reference I tried several products claiming to be able to migrate from a HDD to SSD. These were my experiences:

- EaseUS - https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/personal.html - many sites "review" this "free" software and recommend it. But you have to actually pay for the non-free version if you want to migrate the OS rather than just cloning partitions. The free version leaves you with an un-bootable system.
- DiskGenius - https://www.diskgenius.com/ comes close to working. Says its copying all the partitions including the gpt/mbr but the disk isn't flagged as active or bootable afterwards, meaning you can't boot to it.
- AOMEI backup - https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html - Marketed as a way to migrate your OS for free, but actually that feature is behind a paywall. Tried several times and was not able to produce a bootable drive.
- Macrium Reflect - https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree - Looks like it was working but after several tries wasn't able to create a bootable drive. Doesn't seem to mark destination partitions as bootable / system.